# how to send 01 in hex to serial port with python?

Tags: python, hex

Greeting community,

I need **01**(not 1) in hex to serial port with python. Here's my code:

```
from serial import Serial
sePort = Serial()
sePort.port = "COM3"
sePort.baudrate = 9600
sePort.timeout = 1.0
sePort.writeTimeout =0.1
sePort.open()

sePort.write(0x01)
# I have tried following and few others I can think of, but no luck.
# sePort.write(0x0001)
# sePort.write(0x000001)
```

If i send hex value of 01 correctly, i suppose get something back (this is tested by thirty party software), but whatever I can think of, the results is empty string.
Thanks for your time.

---

updated. per hoboman both of b"\x01" or int.to_bytes(1, 1, 'little') works perfectly.

```
sePort.write(b"\x01")
sePort.write(int.to_bytes(1, 1, 'little'))
```

Thanks again hoboman!

Comment: What do you mean by "no luck"?

Comment: sorry my fault. If i send 01 correctly, i suppose get something back (this is tested by thirty party software), but whatever I can think of, the results is empty string.

Comment: How about `b"\x01"` or `int.to_bytes(1, 1, 'little')`?

Comment: Thanks, hoboman. Both of them works. it saves my life. Thanks a lot!!!